# Stubbing action listener with spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have this in my presenter:

```
private void init() {
    view.subscribeOnButtonClick(new Clickable() {
        @Override
        public void clickPerformed() { sortArray(); }
    });
}
```

And I want to remember this clickable object in my test to trigger it in 'when' part (to simulate button click)

I tried like this:

```
def view = Mock(ArraySorterView)
def clickable
view.subscribeOnButtonClick(_) >> { x -> clickable = x }
when:
clickable.clickPerformed()
```

But it is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I need to write it this way:

```
view.subscribeOnButtonClick(_) >> { Clickable x -> clickable = x }
```

Since if type is not specified, spock considers unnamed parameter as list of arguments.